# JavaScript: How to simultaneously declare a var and let variables in a for loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Although a hypothetical, this case puzzled me. **Do you think it's possible and if so - how**

```
function count() {

    for (
        let i = 0, k = 0; // <<< can this become sth like 'var i = 0; let k = 0' ?
        i < 10; 
        i++, k++ 
    ) { 
        ...
    }

     // ... so that these log as follows:
     console.log( i ); // 10
     console.log( k ); // undefined or Error
}

count();
```

**Note:** It's ok to declare `for (let i=0, k=0; ...)` or `for (var i=0, k=0; ...)`, but can the `i` and `k` be declared simultaneously via `var` and `let` respectively somehow ?

Comment: Sorry, this is not possible and this is for good. i and k are in the loop's scope and thus not visible outside - and it should not at all. Just let count() return some tuple or whatever and you will be happy with it, since everything is properly encapsulated.

Comment: @atmin, sorry but what you write may not be the case when 'i' and 'k' are declared via 'var' as when declared via 'var', both variables are visible outside the block scope of the for loop within the local scope of the count function

Comment: yes, that's why any jslint will detect an error, if a var is declared inside a loop's signatur. Jslint is right (of course it is...), since declaring globals wherever you want would sooner or later result in a mess.

Comment: @atmin, possibly so. I am asking as I have marked a 'hypothetical' question. So you believe there's no way to combine the block and local scope visibility - you chose one or the other , but not both - is this what you're saying ?

Comment: @zaggy: ah, I see! Ok, it may be a nice approach to have some object instead of i and k. But then again the var would not be visible outside the object. So no, I don't see any option.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not allowed by the grammar. You can only have one of the keywords `var`, `let` and `const` in a loop head (or none at all).

The solution is to just put the `var` outside of the loop head, which is a good practice anyway if you want to use it after the loop:

```
function count() {
    var i = 0;
    for (
        let k = 0;
        i < 10; 
        i++, k++ 
    ) { 
        …
    }

    console.log( i ); // 10
    console.log( k ); // ReferenceError
}
count();
```

Comment: Where does it specify the keywords allowed in a loop head in the spec?

Comment: @chiliNUT: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-for-statement

Answer (score 2):

Declare the function-scoped variable outside the for loop.  This kind of happens anyway when you use var keyword within a for loop `for (var i=...)`, the declaration gets hoisted.  Then you are free to use let within the for loop to get block-level scope.  You could even use let for both declarations since they are now not relying on the hoisting provided by var.

```js
function count() {
    var i = 0;
    // or let i = 0;
    for (
        let k = 0;
        i < 10; 
        i++, k++ 
    ) { 
        // 
    }

     // ... so that these log as follows:
     console.log( i ); // 10
     console.log( k ); // undefined or Error
}

count();
```